# Slow boot on 15.10 - dmesg included

Tags: boot

I have an i5 4670k, gtx 760 sli w/ 16gb of RAM. Windows takes 10s to boot, yet Ubuntu takes 37s... I'm not sure why, but I've included my dmesg boot log for you guys. I think it has something to do with not recognizing my keyboard... What do you guys think?

http://pastebin.com/PzZjqbkU